# Python prints return from list pop but when accessing gives 'NoneType' not subscriptable error

Tags: python, list, nonetype

**I am inserting and popping from a Stack in the following code:**

```py
open_stack = util.Stack()

start = []
start.append(problem.getStartState())
open_stack.push(start)

while not open_stack.isEmpty():
    curr_path = open_stack.pop()
    print(type(curr_path))
    if problem.isGoalState(curr_path[-1]):
        return curr_path
    for succ in problem.getSuccessors(curr_path[-1]):
        open_stack.push(curr_path.append(succ[0]))
return False
```

**The print(type(curr_path)) returns:**

`<class 'list'>`

`<class 'NoneType'>`

**The error I get is as follows:**

```py
File "/home/ljagodz/uoft/search/search.py", line 101, in depthFirstSearch
if problem.isGoalState(curr_path[-1]):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

**The Stack class I am using is defined as so:**

```
class Stack:
    "A container with a last-in-first-out (LIFO) queuing policy."

    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def push(self, item):
        "Push 'item' onto the stack"
        self.list.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        "Pop the most recently pushed item from the stack"
        return self.list.pop()

    def isEmpty(self):
        "Returns true if the stack is empty"
        return len(self.list) == 0
```

I cannot understand why the print is acting this way, and why I am getting this error.. The `NoneType` error seems common enough, but I cannot find any explanation analogous to the issue I am experiencing here, as far as I can tell I am not accidentally assigning some list method to a variable as in other *Stackoverflow questions* raising this issue.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely comes from

```
...
for succ in problem.getSuccessors(curr_path[-1]):
    open_stack.push(curr_path.append(succ[0]))
```

the append method of `list` will return `None` object, not the reference to the resulting list. i.e.

```
print(curr_path.append(succ[0]))
```

will print `None`. So you appended `None` to your stack. Try:

```
for succ in problem.getSuccessors(curr_path[-1]):
    open_stack.push(curr_path + [succ[0]]) #use listcomp
```

also see [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

p.s. you can also use [list as stack](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks)

edit: minor error